# I need to add a integer and the number 1 every time a button is pressed

Tags: ios, numbers, parse-platform, ibaction

```
- (IBAction)sneezeButton:(id)sender{
int n = 1;
int sneezes = [PFUser currentUser][@"sneezes"] + n;

}
```

I have an error coming up stating "Arithmetic on pointer to interface 'id',which is not a constant size for this architecture and platform."
Do I have to change the id. Also i just want to add one every time the button is pressed, so if I am totally please help. 
sneeze is from the parse database. also, i know how to update the sneeze string.

Answer (score 1):

Change `[PFUser currentUser][@"sneezes"]` to `[[PFUser currentUser][@"sneezes"] intValue]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can increment this directly on the Parse backend with counters, so long as sneezes is a number, with incrementKey. You can increment with 1 or an arbitrary number.

Example:

```
[[PFUser currentUser] incrementKey:@"sneezes"];
```

http://blog.parse.com/2011/12/07/increment-operators/